# PHP foreach loop not reading values from array

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have simple PHP array with data from checkbox. I need add values into array and then insert data into database. It works but foreach not infringement parameter.

So i testing with increment:

```
$arr = array();
array_push($arr, $_POST['chbox']);
```

and it looks like `123,125` in array (two elements)
Next step is to return number of elements (or values in next step):

```
$id=0;
foreach(  $arr as $row)
{
    $id++;                              
};
```

and returns `$id=1;`

if i'm trying read values:

```
foreach(  $arr as $row)
{
    $row[$id]   
    $id++;
};
```

Return only `123`

Comment: use `$arr = $_POST['chbox'];`

Comment: This is so weird. How would you know that `$row[$id]` returns that? There is no `echo`. Also, if you just want to turn string keys to numeric, take a look at [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php).

Comment: Wow, a lot of stabs at this.  Right after your `array_push`, do a `var_dump($arr);` - what do you get? Then a foreach should be simple: `foreach($arr AS $i => $row) {echo $row[$i];}`.  NOTE - if the `$_POST` is a checkbox, AND the checkbox is NOT checked, then that `$_POST` key will be EMPTY, and will not actually return anything.

Comment: Also to get the number of elements, use `count($arr)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing a foreach, $row is the value already.

```
foreach($arr as $row) {
    echo $row;
    $id++;
}
```

Comment: in php, a loop "body" should not end up with semicolon

Answer (score 1):

In your `foreach()` loop, `$row` is just one array value. Not the array. Replace with `$arr` should solve.

```
$id = 0;
foreach( $arr as $row ){
    echo $arr[$id];
    $id++;
}
echo 'Total items: ' . $id; // OR count( $arr );
```

Comment: Why would you loop with `foreach` if you are using the key (`$id`) like that? xD

Comment: This is how the OP structured the loop. I'm just correcting his variable mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Just try following

```
foreach($arr as $row){
     echo $row;
};
```

Edit 1:
Better use `var_dump($_POST["chkbox"])` or `print_r($_POST["chkbox"])` to see the array you are getting. Then it will be easier for you to decide how to get data.

Comment: Can you please explain what is wrong here? 
For you: http://pastebin.com/x5aSHMrp

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr =array(123,125);

foreach($arr as $arrr):
   echo $arrr.',';
endforeach;
```

Output will be:

```
123,125,
```

Comment: Why the `foreach` convention here? Curly-braces are fairly standard - the format you are using is more typical of php embedded in a template.

Comment: You use Curly-braces. I just provide example, and It become habit for me to use Colon and semicolon Instead of Curly-braces. :)